# Updating a column based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
ID  Type    Food    Drink   Animal
--------------------------------------
1   NULL    Y   N   N
2   NULL    Y   N   N
3   NULL    N   Y   N
4   NULL    N   Y   N
5   NULL    N   N   Y
```

How can I update the Type column based on what boolean is true in other columns. For example
If the 'Food' column is true then the Type would be 'Food' etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` inside an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET Type = 
  CASE
    WHEN Food = 'Y' THEN 'Food'
    WHEN Drink = 'Y' THEN 'Drink'
    WHEN Animal = 'Y' THEN 'Animal'
  END
WHERE ...some condition if necessary...
```

However, this probably isn't necessary at all.  You might consider creating a view that shows you this information rather than storing it in a column.  In case the other booleans change, you would need to always be updating the Type column to match.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW type_vw AS (
  SELECT
      ID, 
      CASE
        WHEN Food = 'Y' THEN 'Food'
        WHEN Drink = 'Y' THEN 'Drink'
        WHEN Animal = 'Y' THEN 'Animal'
      END as Type
  FROM tbl
);
```

Comment: I'm just migrating data from an old database to a new structure. This works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer (as per comment) is to have a normalized database - then it wouldn't be an issue.

The wrong answer is:

```
UPDATE badtable
SET type=(
    CASE
      WHEN Food='Y' THEN 'FOOD'
      WHEN Drink='Y' THEN 'DRINK'
      WHEN Animal='Y' THEN 'ANIMAL'
      ELSE 'WTF?'
)
WHERE type IS NULL
AND (Food='Y' OR Drink='Y' OR Animal='Y');
```

Comment: +1 for the ELSE case.  (actually for the `WHERE` clause which I didn't include in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Type column, you can derive that info, e.g.:

```
select ID, 
    case 
        when Food='Y' then 'Food'
        when Drink='Y' then 'Drink'
        when Animal='Y' then 'Animal'
        else 'None'
    end as Type
from mytable
```

But, I recommend that you change your schema so that you have a separate Type table with columns TypeID and Name. Then, in your main table, you would have a TypeID column.

If there is a requirement that an entity could have more than one Type, you would add an intersection table.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmmm i think your table structure is incorrect.  it would be better to have the types e.g food drink animal in a lookup with a reference from the parent table e.g

parent table

```
id Type
-------
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  3
```

lookup

```
id name
-------
1  food
2  drink
3  animal
```

then you can just do a join on the tables